# Internet Explorer Takes Long Time in Creating and Sending Request ( Chrome works fine )

Tags: asp.net, performance, internet-explorer, iis-7

We have a performance issue in Internet Explore for certain functionality where as the same works fine in Chrome ( Difference in more than a minute on the performance between IE and Chrome )

This is a legacy Asp.Net web application hosted in IIS and the web page has user controls, buttons and grids.

We did some analysis and found that IE is taking close to 60 seconds before sending the request to server after a button is clicked in the page.

Please find attached the network capture screenshots( IE takes around 70 seconds to send the request )

[Network Capture Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jO5Hb.png)
[Network Capture Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GEAM.png)

Any help in resolving this issue will be appreciated

Thanks,
Nanda

Comment: Can you provide the code, which starts the Request? Is it cshtml or JavaScript,... With that few information, it's not possible to find the source of your issue. Except that Internet Explorer is often slower, than other Browsers and doesn't support as many features.

Comment: Hi Nikolaus, Thanks for your response. We are making a post back from aspx page server side button click event ( there are few client side java script for validation which is very fast).. In the Network traffic - "Sending" part takes 90% of the total request time in IE ( all versions) whereas the same request takes only 20% of the total request time in Chrome.

Comment: It's like you wrote: IE is slow in Sending. ;-) Anyway, why are you testing on Internet-Explorer? Do your users use this browser at all? In my opinion, every other browser is faster. Did you test in Edge? Is the performance on Edge that bad?

Comment: Hey @NandaKumar, were you able to find anything? Facing similar issue